# How to attach SOFTASSERT screenshots to Allure report?

Tags: java, selenium, testng, pom.xml, allure

I am a manual tester learning Selenium+Java at the moment. Thanks to a lot of brilliant answers at Stack Overflow, I managed to take screenshot when SoftAssert fails, but I'm now struggling with attaching these screenshot on Allure report. Can someone tell me what to add to my code to have these screenshot attached to the Allure report? Many thanks!!

````
//Override my onAssertFailure:**
public class CustomSoftAssert extends SoftAssert{

     @Override
     public void onAssertFailure(IAssert<?> assertCommand, AssertionError ex)
    {
         WebDriver driver = TestBase.getDriver1();
         Reporting.takeScreenshot(driver);
    }

//takeScreenshot method:
public static void takeScreenshot(WebDriver driver) {

    try 
    {
    TakesScreenshot ts=(TakesScreenshot) driver;
    File source=ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File("./screenshots/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".png"));
    System.out.println("Screenshot taken");
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    System.out.println("Exception while taking screenshot "+e.getMessage());
    } 
}
//onTestFailure method in AllureTestListener**
    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult iTestResult) {
        System.out.println("I am in onTestFailure method " + getTestMethodName(iTestResult) + " failed");
        Object testClass = iTestResult.getInstance();
        WebDriver driver = TestBase.getDriver1();

        // Allure ScreenShotRobot and SaveTestLog
        if (driver instanceof WebDriver) {
            System.out.println("Screenshot captured for test case:" + getTestMethodName(iTestResult));
            saveScreenshotPNG(driver);
        }
        // Save a log on allure.
        saveTextLog(getTestMethodName(iTestResult) + " failed and screenshot taken.");      
    }```
````